# Diff of current and previous version using vim-fugitive

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I know that `:Glog` will populate the quickfix list with all the versions of the file in the current buffer and that I can hit `<enter>` on these to see the file at that particular version, but is there an easy way to see the diff of a particular version with the previous version (to easily see what has changed)?

EDIT: What I'm after is seeing each of these changes in a vertical diff in vim: `git log -p -- path/to/file.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could not get fugitive to do what I want (it either doesn't do it or I don't know how to use it), but I did find the plugin which gives the desired behaviour: https://github.com/kablamo/vim-git-log.

(it does not show the diff in quickfix list but in a full sized buffer, which is OK)

Comment: Sadly, [`vim-git-log`](https://github.com/kablamo/vim-git-log) is dormant with [six outstanding issues](https://github.com/kablamo/vim-git-log/issues). (Last commit: early 2013.) It's also ugly as sin. The only other alternative is [`vimgitlog`](https://github.com/PAntoine/vimgitlog). While actively maintained, the latter is non-trivial to install and (on my machine, at least) fundamentally broken – presumably due to _not_ using `vim-fugitive` under the hood. Who thought that was a good idea? So, I'd love it if someone could fork and begin actively maintaining `vim-git-log` again. _Pleaaase._

Answer (score 25):

This is what I use:

```
:Gdiff [revision]
```

See `:help Gdiff` for other options as well (vertical vs horizontal splits, etc).

For example:

```
:Gdiff HEAD
```

or if you have a revision number (ie: aaffdfdstsdgssetds):

```
:Gdiff aaffdfds
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe it is as simple as:

```
:vert diffsplit #
```

Comment: This does work, so I upvoted, but Gdiff is actually better because it ties directly into the changelist.

Comment: @SkyLeach `:Gvdiff` gets you the best of both :)

Answer (score 4):

First, open the file you want to diff with.

If the change is committed, enter `:Gdiff HEAD~1`.
If the change is **NOT** committed, enter `:Gdiff HEAD`.

Answer (score 3):

When using `:Glog` you can simply press `<cr>` on the line that starts `diff --git`. It will open the diff. You may also want to look into `:Gdiff`. You may want to look at Drew Neil's [vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/), [The Fugitive Series](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/).

For more help see

```
:h fugitive
:h :Glog
:h :Gdiff
```

Comment: The behaviour you described (simply press `<cr>`) is exactly what I'd like, but I don't get a diff, I just get the whole file at that particular revision.

Comment: Make sure you are on the line `diff --get a/somefile b/somefile`.

Comment: So I open a file in vim and then do `:Glog`. This populates a list of versions of the file in the quickfix list. I do not see a `diff --get` line anywhere there... I must be misunderstanding your instructions.

Comment: You have to go to an actual commit object. Do `:cn` or `:cfirst`

Comment: Still couldn't get it to work... Found a plugin with the behaviour I wanted: https://github.com/kablamo/vim-git-log

Comment: I believe that @PeterRincker's answer is dependent on running `:Glog -- %` first. This will (from `:h :Glog`): Load all "... previous commits rather than previous file revisions ..." for the current buffer. This is very different than just `:Glog`, which will: "Load all previous revisions of the current file into the quickfix list." When the buffer contains a commit, instead of a file revision, you will see the `diff --get a/somefile b/somefile` lines and will be able to follow his answer.

Comment: @PeterRincker 's answer works!

Answer (score 2):

#### To diff with its previous version, follow these steps:

1. use `Glog`
2. navigate to the desired version
3. type `C`, which opens the commit
4. go to the line contains `diff --git a/you/file b/you/file` and press `<cr>`

#### Moreover, to diff a previous version with the version in *index* (the working version), you can do this:

1. use `Glog`
2. navigate to the desired version
3. use `Gdiff` in this new window without parameter. **Done!**

`Gdiff` without parameter will diff the current buffer with the one in **index**, which is exactly what you want

You can also consider using the plugin [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired), which provides two maps `]q` and `[q` to navigate the quickfix list. (Also `]Q` and `[Q`)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by following these steps:

1. Change focus to the quickfix window and navigate to the line corresponding to the commit you're interested in.
2. Find the commit hash in the line and yank it (the hash is now in the `0` register.
3. Close the quickfix buffer, and do `:Gdiff <C-r>0`.

That should fire up the proper diff.

**You can automate steps 2 and 3** by adding this mapping to your `.vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap <Leader>gd /\.git<CR>wwwyw<Esc>:cclose<CR>:Gdiff <C-r>0<CR>
```

Notice that the mapping assumes your cursor is at the beginning of the line (before the `.git//` part).

Answer (score 1):

Try `:vert Gdiff`. This will show the diff of the current file in left-right mode.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see diff of a commit is this:

```
:Gedit [revision]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that allows you to diff against a previous revision of the current file. I use this to view the diff between the working copy and revisions "n" times back.

Here's the code to put in your .vimrc (requires https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive):

```
"Diff the current file against n revision (instead of n commit)
function! Diffrev(...)

  let a:target = @%

  "check argument count
  if a:0 == 0
    "no revision number specified
    let a:revnum=0
  else
    "revision number specified
    let a:revnum=a:1
  endif

  let a:hash = system('git log -1 --skip='.a:revnum.' --pretty=format:"%h" ' . a:target)
  execute 'Gdiff' . a:hash
endfunc
```

You can call the function like so (example below diffs against 3rd revision back):

`:call Diffrev(2)`