# Comparing files with itself in VIM or any other method

Tags: git, vim

I have a file that I want to compare with itself. The first file is the  original file and the second file is the one being developed. One method would be `git diff`, but wont work, if the original itself has been changed and not staged yet. Another method would be to make a copy of it on the file system and use the `diff` and `watch` command. This isnt efficient because of creation and deletion of temp files.

I would like to hence try the `dodiff` command in VIM. VIM can store files as buffer in memory and hence my question is how should I do it?

Please note that the files are not changed from within the vim environment, but from an external editor.

Example:

1. file1.txt - original
2. This contents are now changed in the file1.txt
3. load file1.txt in vim
4. The contents of the file are again changed
5. compare 3 wih 4.
6. The contents of the file are again changed
7. compare 3 with 6 automatically, maybe something like automatic refresh.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802629/diff-of-current-and-previous-version-using-vim-fugitive

Comment: @Edwin i shud have been clear, the files are changed from outside the vim environment. In the related post, the revisions are maintained from inside the vim.

Comment: and after the 4th step is no commit done, right?

Comment: @Edwin no commit is done in the entire process. moreover, the files in question maybe not under version control as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution will be to start `:windo diffthis` 
then create a new buffer (a temp file) `:vert diffsplit file1.txt~` (when you have `file1.txt`) and then read the content in this new buffer `:read file1.txt`

Comment: further comments to the answer is written below in a separate answer...

Answer (score 2):

Inside Vim, edited files are read into memory *buffers*. To create a "snapshot" of the file contents at a certain point in time, you can create a new buffer, and copy the contents from the original buffer to it, using either `:%yank | new %.snapshot | put | 1delete _` (clobbers the default register), or `:let contents = getline(1, '$') | new %.snapshot | call setline(1, contents)` (longer), or more comfortably through my [clone plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4896) via `:SCloneAs %.snapshot`.

With `:set autoread`, the original buffer will automatically update to any changes done outside of Vim. You can then diff both windows via `:windo diffthis`, and update the diff (if necessary) with `:diffupdate`.

Of course, you can also create new snapshots via `:SCloneAs %.snapshot2`; remove a snapshot via `:bdelete`.

Answer (score 2):

This is to complete Edwin's answer, that would not fit in a comment.

Another solution will be to load test.yml `vim test.yml` and then `:windo diffthis`. 
Then create a new buffer (a temp file) `:vert diffsplit test_original.yml` and then read the content in this new buffer `:read test.yml`.

At this point you should have two windows - one with test_original.yml and the other with test.yml. You have to delete the first line ( dd ) in the test_original.yml, because read appends to the file and hence there is an extra line. The problem here is that vim marks all the lines as changed.

[image]

In order to fix this, run `:diffoff` and again `:windo diffthis`.  Now you would only see one line.

Finally, make the changes externally to test.yml and if you want to see the changes then run `:edit`, Now you should only see the changes between the original and the changed file.

[image]

Once over, just quit with qa!. Since test_original.yml has not been written ( w ), no copy on the filesystem has been made.

Subsequent changes externally, must be reloaded into vim by using the `:edit` or `:checktime` command

Comment: you can use `:set autoread` after you do the `dd` of the first line and will get you the diff too